# washer method calculus help

Tags: calculus

The question is: "Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the line $y = 5$ using washer method outer - inner formula
 the functions to graph are: $y = x^2$, $y = 2x$. [sic, original reads, approximately, "Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by $y = x^2$ and $y = 2x$ about $y = 5$."]

Comment: are the 5-x^2 and the 5-2x supposed to be squared and then foiled before plugging them into the outer-inner formula??

Comment: If we are rotating the finite region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=2x$ about the line $y=5$, yes. But I am now *very doubtful* about that interpretation, Surely the problem specifies the axis of rotation. If it is a many part problem, maybe the axis of rotation is given in a header at the beginning.  I cannot give advice until I am sure of the wording.

Comment: it`s rotating around the line y = 5

Comment: How do you know that is the axis of rotation?  Does the problem say so?  And what is the region we are rotating about the line $y=5$?  That is probably also specified. Your leaving out the axis of rotation in the problem has already cost you and me time.

Comment: it doesn`t say an axis of rotation. i just reread the question.

Comment: it just says "the region bounded by y = x^2 and y = 2x about y = 5"

Comment: it doesn`t mention the words "axis of rotation at all"

Comment: OK, that's finally clear.  Why could it not have been said at the beginning? Yes, outer radius $5-x^2$, inner radius $5-2x$, $x$ going $0$ to $2$, so volume is $\int_0^2 \pi\left( (5-x^2)^2-(5-2x)^2  \right)\,dx$.

Comment: "About $y=5$ is good enough. If in your original question you  had written "the region bounded by $\dots$" you probably would have received an answer in under 5 minutes.

Comment: @BrianTung: My guess is that the source is in the English language.

Comment: @Natalie: "About" in this context means "around"; therefore, "about $y = 5$" means revolution of that region around the axis $y = 5$.  It is unfortunate, but when one says "that's literally what the directions are," the expectation is that you have given a word-for-word exact copy of the directions, which this wasn't.  It may sound like a trivial thing, but some people on this site answer dozens of questions a day, and a few minutes working out what an inaccurate transcription says adds up.  Not chastising you, just pointing out that it can get frustrating.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I would agree, at this point.

Comment: Okay well my apologies guys. How long is this question going to be on hold for? @BrianTung

Comment: I don't know; I didn't vote to put it on hold.  There didn't seem to be much point, since it was already answered, and the comment thread here provides most of the context that's needed.  On the other hand, since there's already an answer, do you really need it to be re-opened?

Answer (score 1):

To use the washer method, you calculate a difference of volumes by considering radial distances and using the formula $\pi r^{2}$. Thus, the problem comes down to finding appropriate expressions for $r$.

You want to volume obtained by rotating the region between $y=x^{2}$ and $y=2x$ about the line $y=5$ so we do this stepwise:

1). Since you are rotating around a line parallel to the $x$-axis using the washer methhod, you will be integrating with respect to $x$, which runs from $0$ to $2$.

2). . the distance from the line $y=5$ to the curve given by $y=x^{2}$ is $5-x^{2}$ so the volume we obtain by rotating the region between these curves is

$$\pi \int_{0}^{2}(5-x^{2})^{2}dx$$

3). the distance from the line $y=5$ to the curve given by $y=2x$ is $5-2x$ so the volume we obtain by rotating the region between these curves is

$$\pi \int_{0}^{2}(5-2x)^{2}dx$$

4). The volume we want is then the difference $$\pi \int_{0}^{2}(5-x^{2})^{2}dx-\pi \int_{0}^{2}(5-2x)^{2}dx=\frac{446}{15}\pi -\frac{62}{3}\pi \approx 28.5$$